# Err bad request 404 not found

Tags: axios

GET METHOD USING AXIOS ERROR 404 NOT FOUND
Its backend api and router
[Backend api](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DHpGw.png)
[Router](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9nRwc.png)

Im try to fetch data form backend
[Proxy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WQc8U.png)
[React code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BaJT5.png)

In postman its working properly but connect with frontend and backend means im getting thes type of error[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1zHDp.png)

Please help me to rectify this problem im try much more ways but its not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmmm... firstly it looks like you are trying to hit localhost:4000, and your proxy is set to allow requests to 8800, looks like you need to allow the 4000 port not the 8800 in proxy, and also how about the additional /api? is it really part of the final URL?

I would recommend in proxy setting only  *`"proxy": "http://localhost:4000"`* (*or whatever port your server is listening on*), and, on the server, `app.use(/api/users)` (unless you really have a `/api/api`)

(proxy is just allowing the domain to be access)

and then in the get stats for testing purposes i would include the full URL i assume it should be sth like `http://localhost:4000/api/users/stats"`

RECOMFIRM on what port is your sever listening to, if you are using express it should be somewhere "app.listen(4000  ...." and the port variable may be hardcoded like above '4000' or it maybe in another variable or it can be also stored in .env file depending on how your project is set up

if your confirm that it is listening on port 4000 your final server setup should be

app.use(/api/users)

router.get("/stats")

In proxy in package.json file `(REMEMBER IT HAS TO BE A package.json on the client side so probably in client/src/` add the "http://localhost:4000"

an in the getStats make it

```
const res = await axios.get("http://localhost:4000/api/users/stats,   ....   )"
```

You can later think how you can shorten the URL in this function

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).